# API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role, yet role seems to have them attached (sts assume role)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I test my API Gateway but I get:

```
Sat Nov 09 02:12:13 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error:  
API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role
arn:aws:iam::193693970645:role/service-role/DoubleMeLambda-role-0erzzpmz`
```

However, my API Gateway uses:

```
arn:aws:iam::193693970645:role/service-role/DoubleMeLambda-role-0erzzpmz
```

and that role has

[image]

I made it super powerful (*) to try and get it to work but that didn't help

The lambda uses the same role (not ideal in real world I know but it seems like it should work):

[image]

I edited the trust relationship for that role and added:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure a trust relationship between your IAM role and API gateway / lambda so that it can assume your IAM role:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/edit_trust.html

The permission you have granted, is for anyone with that role to be able to assume another role, rather than allowing anyone to assume that role.

Comment: I'm sure this is the way but please can you give a little more info.  I went to the role and edited trust relationship and added an entry using `"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"` but i still get the error.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant your trust relationship should be ```"Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"``` since it is API Gateway that is assuming that role